# Java parent class using child class attributes

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public animal{

        String name;
        String species;

        public introduction(){
                System.out.println("Hi, my name is" + name +", i am a " + species);
        }
}

public dog extends animal{
        String species = "dog";
}
```

I am wondering if i were to build more child classes like cat, bird etc, with with their unique `species` variable. If there a way whereby I can make them self-introduce different according to their species?

I understand that I am asking a parent class to access a child-class attribute, which seems to defeat the purpose of inheritance in the first place, but I am not sure what is a more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `animal.class` you already seem to have defined a public member variable `name` and `species`. This is obviously part of the child classes namely `cat.class` and `dog.class`

Your parent class has syntax errors function should return `void` like so:

```
public void introduction(){
       System.out.println("Hi, my name is" + name +", i am a " + species);
}
```

Your child classes would look like this:

```
class Cat extends Animal{
 
  public Cat(){
    super.name = "tom"
    super.species = "cat"
  }

}

class Mouse extends Animal{
 
  public Mouse(){
    super.name = "jerry" //simply calling name = "jerry" will work as this is inherited.
    super.species = "mouse"
  }

}
```

Note that I haven't child level member variables, and you can call them like so:

```
Animal cat = new Cat();
Animal mouse = new Mouse();

cat.introduction(); // prints Hi, my name is tom...
mouse.introduction(); //prints Hi, my name is jerry ...
```

Also, it is a good practise to follow Programming guidelines as CamelCasing your classes. eg(Animal instead of animal)

Comment: You don't need `super` in the constructor. The field is already inherited

Comment: I know, I assumed OP is new to java and didn't want to confuse him/her

Comment: I have tried using `this.name = "Tom"` & `this.species = "cat"`, but did not work; is it because the keyword `this` by default assign the value to the child-level attribute? and using `super` will assign the value to the parent attribute? Is that correct?

Comment: Your parent class variables must be public or protected to be inherited, if you don’t explicitly say it’s packaged private but public within the package.